# Current weather conditions JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am a beginner in JQuery and I am trying to get current weather conditions with Yahoo API.

```js
$(function() {

  var weatherUrl = 'https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20item.condition%20from%20weather.forecast%20where%20woeid%20in%20(select%20woeid%20from%20geo.places(1)%20where%20text%3D%22lyon%22)%20and%20u%3D%22c%22&format=json&env=store%3A%2F%2Fdatatables.org%2Falltableswithkeys'

  $.getJSON(weatherUrl, function(data) {
    var result = data.query.results.channel.item.condition;
    var code = result.code;
    var currently = result.text;
    var temp = result.temp;
    var image = 'https://s.yimg.com/zz/combo?a/i/us/nws/weather/gr/' + result.code + 'd.png';
    var units = 'C'


    html = '<h2><i class="icon-' + code + '"></i> ' + temp + '&deg;' + units + '</h2>';
    html += '<ul><li>' + 'Lyon' + ', ' + 'France' + '</li>';
    html += '<li class="currently">' + currently + '</li>';
    $("#weather").html(html);
  });

});
```

```html
<html>
<p class="back">
  <div id="weather"></div>
</p>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

</html>
```

How can I insert html in div "weather"?

Comment: But your code already does that. So what should be different?

Comment: It is doing that already

Comment: So, my code is okay? Because, nothing appears when I run my code!

Comment: do you get a response from the `$.getJSON` function?